# How to add zoom and flip to an image using css/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add both flip and zoom effects, But I am able to achieve only one effect.

Use case is when I click on the Image the image will zoom, now i need to add the flip effect before the mouseleave the image.

Can anyone please help me out with the output using my code.

here it is what I have tried :

**HTML**

```
  <div class="flip">
<div class = 'card'>
        <img src="http://cdn.ndtv.com/tech/images/doodle_for_google_2013.jpg" class="zoom_img" />
</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.zoom_img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    /* -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.1s ease-in; */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.zoom_img_press {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}
.flip {
    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card .flipped {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.flip').click(function(){
            $(this).find('.zoom_img').addClass('zoom_img_press').mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('zoom_img_press');
            });
        });
$(this).find('.zoom_img').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('flipped');
            });
       });

    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VzkJf/)

Comment: You aren't using the classes for the flip transitions.

Comment: Ya know… other than the click, I'm not even sure if jQuery is necessary.  But to learn about flips and such… check out this page - http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Answer (score 3):

Try this i think it will help you..

Class with multiple transform.

```
.zoom-flipper{
    -moz-transform: scale(2.2) rotatex(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.2) rotatex(-180deg);
    -o-transform: scale(2.2) rotatex(-180deg);
    transform: scale(2.2) rotatex(-180deg);    
}
```

Corresponding Script:

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.zoom_img').addClass('zoom-flipper').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('zoom-flipper');
    });
});
```

Here is the <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VzkJf/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate JavaScript functions then write jQuery code to manipulate the css for the image within the functions. JQuery css manipulation code example:

```
 $(".className").css({"background-color":"black","font-size":"12px"});
```

You can set any css property within the curly brackets.

Then you can call the JavaScript functions on the elements DOM events. So the zoom function will be called with the onClick event and the flip function will be called on the onMouseOut event.